# How should I use variables in a generic class/form?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a form that is combined of two user controls, one shows a list of objects and the other shows details of the selected object in the list. This form should work for two types of classes, e.g. Animals and Persons. Both classes have mostly similar attributes, e.g. Name, Age but are not exactly the same. So I am working on making the form generic.
[The form looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOr4Y.png)

I've set up the form using mainly [this](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics) as a reference. My code looks like this:

```
public partial class MyForm<T> : Form
    {
        public MyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myListUserControl1.ItemSelected += MyListUserControl1_ItemSelected;
        }

        private void MyListUserControl1_ItemSelected(T selectedItem)
        {
            myDetailsUserControl1.SelectItem(selectedItem);
        }

        internal void InitializeData(List<T> items)
        {
            myListUserControl1.SetList(items);
            myDetailsUserControl1.SetList(items);
        }
    }
```

The user control to display the list:

```
public partial class MyListUserControl<T> : XtraUserControl
{
    public delegate void ItemSelectedEventHandler(T selectedItem);
    public event ItemSelectedEventHandler ItemSelected;
    public MyListUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetList(List<T> items)
    {

        gridControl1.DataSource = items;
    }

    private void gridView1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = GetSelectedItem();
        if (ItemSelected != null)
            ItemSelected(item);
    }

    private T GetSelectedItem()
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(gridView1.GetRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle), typeof(T));
        //return gridView1.GetRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle) as Animal;
    }
}
```

The user control to display details of the selected item:

```
public partial class MyDetailsUserControl<T> : XtraUserControl
    {
        private List<T> items;
        public MyDetailsUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        internal void SetList(List<T> _items)
        {
            items = _items;
        }

        internal void SelectItem(T selectedItem)
        {
            if (IsAnimal(selectedItem))
            {
                textName.Text = (selectedItem as Animal).ThingName;
                textAge.Text = ((selectedItem as Animal).Age).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                textName.Text = (selectedItem as Person).ThingName;
                textAge.Text = ((selectedItem as Person).Age).ToString();
            }
        }

        public bool IsAnimal(T item)
        {
            Animal a = item as Animal;
            if (a == null)
                return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

The classes:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal() { }
    public enum AnimalType { Dog, Shark, Cat};
    public string ThingName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public AnimalType Type { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public Person() { }
    public string ThingName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm wondering what the best way to use the variables is, for example in the **SelectItem** function in **MyDetailsUserControl**. After a lot of googling I have two ways in mind but I'm not sure which one is better and why.

1. Similar to what I have right now, using if/else in the functions that need them. Maybe setting an enum type when the form is initialized to have easier access to which type it is.
2. Create derived forms from **MyForm**, such as **MyAnimalForm** and **MyPersonForm** and then have something like a virtual function in **MyForm** that is overridden in the derived forms. But this would require me to make derived versions of the user controls as well so it feels a bit redundant since I only need the form to work for two types.

I also have a problem with how I return the type in **GetSelectedItem** function in **MyListUserControl**, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you only need it to work for two classes have you considered just having two derived classes from a single base class?

Comment: If both `Animal` and `Person` have properties `ThingName` and `Age` you could refactor that to a separate class which `Person` and `Animal` then extend from.

Comment: I wouldn't use generics here at all. If the classes have similar properties, it rather sounds like they should inherit from a common base class or implement an interface that declares those properties. Then your form doesn't need to be generic but can work with the interface.

Comment: What if T is neither Animal nor Person? As is, the data of the last Animal / Person would be shown. :( Also a little tip from experience: If you find yourself having to if/else on a list of types, you may probably want to reconsider your architecture.

Comment: @Fildor that's the feeling I got about using if/else, it's good to get a confirmation that it was a valid feeling :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by Chris in the comment you definitely should to :

Or to create a base class for the Properties shared by both Animal and person.

```
 public class LivingThing
 {
    public string ThingName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
  }

   public class Animal : LivingThing
   {
        public Animal() { }
        public enum AnimalType { Dog, Shark, Cat};
        public AnimalType Type { get; set; }
   }

   public class Person : LivingThing
   {
       public Person() { }
   }
```

And when you are declaring the generic 
must restrict to this new Base type

```
public partial class MyDetailsUserControl<T> : XtraUserControl ) where T : LivingThing
```

Or you can Create an Interface `ILivingThing`

```
public interface ILivingThing
{
    string ThingName { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}  

 public class Animal : ILivingThing
 {
     public Animal() { }
     public enum AnimalType { Dog, Shark, Cat};
     public AnimalType Type { get; set; }
     public  string ThingName { get; set; }
     public  int Age { get; set; }
 }

 public class Person : ILivingThing
 {
     public Person() { }
     public  string ThingName { get; set; }
     public  int Age { get; set; }
 }
```

and had with the same way add the restriction 
must restrict to this new Base type

```
public partial class MyDetailsUserControl<T> : XtraUserControl ) where T : ILivingThing
```

Of course you should find a correct and adequat name for `LivingThing`